# Set the first option value of a select using jquery

Tags: jquery, select

Does anyone know how to set the first option value of a select using jquery? For example i have the following select tag.

```
<select id = "my-id">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I want to set the value. So far I have unsuccessfully attempted the following.

```
$("select#my-id").first().val("hello world");

document.getElementById('my-id').value="hello world";

$("select#my-id option")
         .each(function() {
                 this.text = query.eguide;
                 this.value =query.eguide;});
```

Comment: I took it as trying to actually change the value attribute of the first option, not making the first option be selected.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but very similar.

Comment: Ive looked at that question above. I dont think its a duplicate. Im trying to set the value, not set it as selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#my-id option:first").attr("value", "blahblah");
```

or (thanks to @Tom)

```
$("#my-id option:first").val("blahblah");
```

This will set the `val` attribute to `blahblah`. Obviously changing `blahblah` to whatever you need.

Comment: Does one have to use `attr("value", ...)` or would `val(...)` also work?

Comment: Just tested it now - It seems to do the same with, I will update the answer. You can see for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/N5h8F/

Answer (score 2):

And a solution with plain js you can try:

```
document.getElementById("my-id").options[0].value="TEST";
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ykf5z/)

Comment: I guess the downvote is because of **[not enough jQuery](http://needsmorejquery.com/)** ?